# Is there a better way of getting the selected option than string concatenation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this:

```
function addSelectOnChange(select_id,selected_cb) {
    $(select_id).live("change",function() {
         var value = $(select_id + " option:selected").val();
         if(value) {
             selected_cb(value);
         }
    });
}
```

Is there another way of telling jQuery that I want to get the selected option, than by concatenating the selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the examples of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). You can do:

```
var value = $(select_id).val();
```

Better in this case:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

or even (see [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement)):

```
var value = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the filter.

Just do `$(selector).val()` on a dropdown and jquery will give you the selected value.